# Opening links from an external window into my main window

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a webapp (vb.net and aspx) currently that displays quite a bit of information on the screen at any given time.

part of the app is a diary system that shows tasks that are due, overdue etc. When a task is clicked on it takes you to the matter that contains the task.

What I would like to do is give my users the ability to have that task diary open in a separate window, and when they click an item in that window it opens the matter in the main window of the webapp.

At the moment it just opens the matter in the window that the task diary is in.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889596/asp-net-how-to-pass-window-returnvalue-to-c-sharp-code is in C# but the principle is similar, open the task as modal, then read the value from hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tend to think it is better to flip this around.

Display, show, have a pick list, and then when the user clicks on a row, you pop as a dialog the ONE thing/record for the user to focus on, work on, and do their job. They then close that one thing, and are ready to work on and do battle with the next task.

I mention/note/suggest the above design pattern, since the issue with a pop-up floating form is that your main form CAN NOT have ANY post-backs, or the dialog popup will also collapse.

In other words, unless that big main edit/form area does NOT do any post backs, then your desired design will not work. (you can't keep the popup list/form showing if ANY post back is to occur). You MIGHT be able to wrap the main form area in an update panel, and that would/might allow the popup list to remain open.

So, the pattern I am suggesting is this:

[image]

So, in above, we show the pick list, and then pop the edit area. Again, in most cases, while the user can edit the data in the popup, often it is difficult to allow post-backs in the popup (they collapse with a post back).

The other approach?

Simple hide the pick list/grid when you click on a row. So, say like this:

[image]

The above works well, since then the edit page can have page post backs during its operation (this tends to work with existing complex forms). All the above does is when you click on a row is we hide the grid pick list, and then load the div, and show the div. As noted, this design works well for existing complex forms.

Not only does above work well,  but behaves much like what is all the rage today. That's the so called SPA (single page application). And this design pattern also touch friendly. And by not using dialogs, then WHEN  we need to pop a dialog we can. It's both difficult to pop multiple nested dialogs, and is often confusing to the user. So starting out without any dialogs means we can with greater ease pop a dialog when needed. It becomes progressively difficult to pop dialogs when existing dialogs are active. As noted multiple dialogs are not phone nor touch friendly.

I somewhat prefer the first example of gridview and pop to edit.

However the second example has no popups, and thus is more touch friendly, and is more able to adopt css that is responsive (able to resize for mobile phones). Turns out this choice is easiest from a coding standpoint (no dialogs, but just plain vb code and markup).

Now, I suppose we could try and pop a list of hotels, and then when you click on a row, we load up the main form. However, I not really sure that UI is all that great. You might just as well have a list on the left side pane, and then when you click on a row, then the form loads/displays on the right side.

So, it can be challenging to KEEP the popup dialog open during the form editing process. And then things like what occurs if the user not saved, or finished the form edit and then they click on that floating list? (then what do you do???).

So, I can if you ask try posting above, and we float a popup of hotels and then when we click on a row in that floating dialog, then we load up the main page form with information to edit. As noted, this "might" work if we place the main page form inside of an update panel, since as noted, any full-page post-back will no doubt collapse the popup dialog.

So, you can for sure achieve this goal, but that may well force you to re-design the main form edit area to NOT have any post-backs, and it will have to all be re-coded as ajax and web methods.

I think the choice here comes down to how complex the edit form/page is, and does it require post-backs during general operation of that page?

I am happy to post some of the vb.net code for the above web pages, and how the above pages work.

Comment: Good job, nice UX.